# Retrieve HTML within jQuery plugin image click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using a plugin that lets me scroll and zoom on an image.

I'm trying to click the following img to get the values for `left` and `top` as specified below.

```
<img id="zoom_mw" src="<?php echo $small_image; ?>" data-zoom-image="<?php echo $large_image; ?>" />
```

I get the following html which updates as I move the cursor around the screen (achieved by the jQuery plugin):

```
<div class="zoomLens" style="float: right; overflow: hidden; z-index: 999; -webkit-transform: translateZ(0px); opacity: 0.4; zoom: 1; width: 16px; height: 16px; cursor: crosshair; border: 1px solid rgb(0, 0, 0); position: absolute; border-radius: 104px; left: 177px; top: 228px; display: none; background-color: white; background-position: 0px 0px; background-repeat: no-repeat;">&nbsp;</div>
```

I need to use jQuery to get the values `left` and `top` from within `zoomLens`.

I have tried the following but it's returning `undefined`.

```
$("#zoom_mw").click(function(){
    var relX = $( "div#zoomContainer" ).html();
    var relY = $( "div#zoomLens" ).html();
    $('#coordinates').html('x: ' + relX + ' y : ' + relY);
});
```

Any ideas of how to get this from the html?
Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [.css()](http://api.jquery.com/css/) to read the style values

```
$("#zoom_mw").click(function(){
    var $zoomLens = $( ".zoomLens" );
    var relX = $zoomLens.css('left');
    var relY = $zoomLens.css('top');
    $('#coordinates').html('x: ' + relX + ' y : ' + relY);
});
```

Comment: Perfect, except div.zoomLens, not # :)

Answer (score 0):

You can get offset values with following code:

```
$("#zoom_mw").click(function(){
  var pos = $( "div#zoomLens" ).offset();
  $('#coordinates').html('x: ' + pos.top + ' y : ' + pos.left);
});
```